# How to get number of results in strings.Contains?

Tags: go

When you want to check if a string contains some substring, you do it this way:

```
msg = "Lorem ipsum example of lorem ipsum."
if strings.Contains(msg, "ipsum") {
   fmt.Println("contains word ipsum")
}
```

How can I find out how many times the word "ipsum" appears in **msg**?

Comment: http://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Count

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use

> [strings.Count(string, substring)](http://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Count)

Count counts the number of non-overlapping instances of substring in string.

To use your example:

```
msg := "Lorem ipsum example of lorem ipsum."
fmt.Printf("contains %d occurences of ipsum", strings.Count(msg, "ipsum"))
```

Comment: It is ok but it think that this is not good to use because of case sensitive. I'm not sure but I think that you can't set in Count function case insesitive

Comment: To ignore case, you can convert both the string ("haystack") and the substring ("needle") to lowercase, using strings.ToLower